# Upload multiple files with icon button

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I want to create form with icon button. When a user clicks on the icon browser dialog will open and allow him to choose file. After he finishes, he can click again on the icon and choose another file (limited to X files).

How can I do that?

This is what I have now: (hide = display:none)

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <img class="uploadFileImg" alt="" src="images/photoIconOn.png"> <br /><br/>
    <span class="fileNameBox"></span>
    <input type='file' name='file[]' class='file-field hide' maxlength='2' accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif" />

</form>
```

js:

```
$(".uploadFileImg").on('click',function(){
   $(".file-field").trigger('click'); 

    var new_field = $("<input type='file[]' class='form-control file-field hide'>");
    $(this).closest('form').append(new_field);     

});
```

Check file validation:

```
$(function() {
    $('input.file-field').on('change', function(e) {
        var filename = $(this).val();
        if (!(/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i).test(filename)) {
            this.value = '';
            $(this).closest('form').find('.fileNameBox').html("<span class='valid_msg'>Only images allowed</span>");
        }
        else
            $(this).closest('form').find('.fileNameBox').html("Image: " + filename + " <button class='clear_file btn btn-default btn-xs'>remove</button>");
  });
});
```

Remove files:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click','.clear_file',function() {
        $(this).closest('form').find('input.file-field').val("")
        $(this).closest('form').find('.fileNameBox').html("");
  });
});
```

Comment: specify errors , you see ..

Answer (score 0):

Use this [jquery file upload plugin](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/index.html) - handling file uploads cross browser compatible is a hard task and somebody did the hard work already.

The plugin can be configured to do exactly what you requested, see the demo.